# Error calling GetProcessDPIAwareness

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-xe8

I am trying to port `GetProcessDPIAwareness` from the Windows 8.1 SDK. However when I try to start this program it just crashes with the error:

`system exception (code 0xc0000409) at 0x77929990'`

The function is present in `shcore.dll`. I am running `Windows 8.1` so it should work but it doesn't.

```
program Test;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Winapi.Windows;

const
  shcore = 'shcore.dll';

type
  HANDLE = THandle;

  PROCESS_DPI_AWARENESS = (
    PROCESS_DPI_UNAWARE = 0,
    PROCESS_SYSTEM_DPI_AWARE = 1,
    PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE = 2
  );

function GetProcessDPIAwareness(
  {_In_}  hprocess: HANDLE;
  {_Out_} out value: PROCESS_DPI_AWARENESS
): HRESULT; WINAPI; external  name 'GetProcessDPIAwareness';

var
  DPI: PROCESS_DPI_AWARENESS;
begin
  GetProcessDPIAwareness(0, DPI); // crashes here
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: It's `GetProcessDpiAwareness`, not `GetProcessDPIAwareness`.

Comment: That's not your real program. Please don't post fake code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan what is your thought here ?

Comment: @TridenT the code does not compile

Comment: @TLama, that is exactly the cause.

Comment: @UweRaabe How does that explain a stack overflow NTSTATUS code?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After adding the dll name to the external declaration the code actually compiles. Then you only have to follow the advice given by TLama and use the correct procedure name:

```
function GetProcessDpiAwareness(
  {_In_}  hprocess: HANDLE;
  {_Out_} out value: PROCESS_DPI_AWARENESS
): HRESULT; WINAPI; external shcore;
```

Comment: Good catch. Just because the Delphi compiler isn't case sensitive doesn't mean that GetProcAddress is case insensitive.